# How with Route::resource to apply middleware only to store/update?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-middleware

I need to set DataSavingClearing middleware when data is stored/updated, like

```
Route::put('data-put', array('as' => 'data-put', 'uses' => 'Controller@update'))->middleware('DataSavingClearing:notes');
```

Parameter notes is some additive parameter for DataSavingClearing.

But my many routes are defined with resource

```
Route::resource('items', 'Controller', [ 'except' => ['show' ] ] );  // ->middleware('DataSavingClearing');
```

Can I set someway to show in line above that middleware DataSavingClearing must be applied only to store/update   ?

laravel/framework 9.19

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to put the DataSavingClearing middleware only in store and update method at your items resource right ?

Comment: Yes, only that.

Comment: as the example below, you can use it in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add middleware for certain routes in the constructor of the controller like this:

```
/**
 * Enforce middleware.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['create', 'store', 'edit', 'delete']]);
    // Alternativly
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#controller-middleware)

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in your [controller's constructor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#controller-middleware):

```php
class Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('DataSavingClearing:notes')->except('show');
    }
}
```

Or the other way round:

```php
class Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('DataSavingClearing:notes')->only('store', 'update');
    }
}
```